# SegFault in class destructor

Tags: c++, class, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, destructor

I am constructing a Polynomial class in C++. Currently I am reading in input and creating a Polynomial object with a degree and coefficient (double) array.

Ex.

```
6x^3+7.4x^2-3.0x+9
Polynomial 
----------
  degree = 3
  coefficients[0] = 6
  coefficients[1] = 7.4
  coefficients[2] = 3.0
  coefficients[3] = 9
```

I am getting an error when I am deleting an instance of my class. I am not sure what the problem is exactly...along with a `SEGFAULT` my error looks like:

```
Segmentation fault: 11

0x00007ffff71fdfbd in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>, 
    str=0x7ffff7304ad8 "free(): invalid next size (fast)", action=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4983
_int_free (have_lock=0, p=<optimized out>, av=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3850
__GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2960
```

My constructors looks like:

```
/* Constructor for Polynomial */
Polynomial::Polynomial ()
{
    degree = 0;
    coefficients = new double [1];
    coefficients[0] = 0;
}

Polynomial::Polynomial (const Polynomial & P)
{
    *this = P;
}
```

Assignment Operator:

```
Polynomial & Polynomial::operator = (const Polynomial & P)
{
    if (this != &P){
        degree = P.degree;
        coefficients = new double [P.degree + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= P.degree; i++)
            coefficients[i] = P.coefficients[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

My destructor looks like:

```
/* Destructor for Polynomial */
Polynomial::~Polynomial ()
{
    delete [] coefficients; <--ERROR HERE
}
```

My implementation inside my main() looks like this:

```
vector<Polynomial> Polys;
Polynomial *P1 = new Polynomial();
...
P1->degree = degreeInt;
P1->coefficients[idx] = coefficient;
Polys.push_back(*P1);
delete P1; <-- ERROR HERE
// Pushed Polynomial to Vector, create a new Polynomial object
P1 = new Polynomial();
```

Comment: You need an assignment operator and copy constructor, but there's no apparent reason why `coefficients` should be dynamically allocated in the first place.

Comment: `P1->coefficients[idx] = coefficient;` is possibly out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Your first step is to learn the difference between a memory leak and a segfault.

Comment: A memory leak is when you forget to delete something, not when you get an error while trying to delete something.

Comment: Keeping my current implementation of the array [] coefficients I implemented a copy constructor and assignment operator that look like: `degree = P.degree; coefficients = new double [degree + 1]; for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) coefficients[i] = P.coefficients[i];` This isn't working, how can I modify this to work? @EJP

Comment: Your assignment operator has a memory leak. You are not freeing the old array before assigning a new array. And if you are going to implement the copy constructor in terms of the assignment operator, the constructor still needs to initialize members beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Your code crashes because you are not following the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Your `push_back()` call makes a copy of the input object, but your class is missing an explicit copy constructor.  The compiler provides a default one, but it simply copies the `coefficients` pointer from one object to another, so you end up with multiple objects trying to free the same array and crash.

You need a custom copy constructor that makes a deep copy of the `coefficients` array.  Try something more like this instead:

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    std::size_t degree;
    double *coefficients;

public:
    Polynomial(std::size_t aDegree = 0);
    Polynomial(const Polynomial &src);
    ~Polynomial();

    Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial &src);

    void setDegree(std::size_t value);
    void setCoefficient(std::size_t idx, double value);
};

Polynomial::Polynomial(std::size_t aDegree)
    : degree(aDegree), coefficients(0)
{
    if (degree == std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())
        throw std::domain_error("invalid degree value");

    coefficients = new double[degree + 1];
    std::fill(coefficients, coefficients + (degree + 1), double(0)); 
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial &src)
    : degree(src.degree), coefficients(0)
{
    coefficients = new double[degree + 1];
    std::copy(src.coefficients, src.coefficients + (degree + 1), coefficients);
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{
    delete[] coefficients;
}

Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial &src)
{
    if (&src != this)
    {
        Polynomial tmp(src);
        std::swap(degree, tmp.degree);
        std::swap(coefficients, tmp.coefficients);
    }
    return *this;
}

void Polynomial::setDegree(std::size_t value)
{
    if (degree != value)
    {
        if (value == std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())
            throw std::domain_error("invalid degree value");

        double *new_coefficients = new double[value + 1];

        std::copy(coefficients, coefficients + (std::min(degree, value) + 1), new_coefficients);
        if (value > degree)
            std::fill(new_coefficients + (degree + 1), new_coefficients + (value + 1), double(0)); 

        delete[] coefficients;
        coefficients = new_coefficients;
        degree = value;

        /*
        alternatively:

        Polynomial tmp(value);
        std::copy(coefficients, coefficients + (std::min(degree, value) + 1), tmp.coefficients);
        std::swap(degree, tmp.degree);
        std::swap(coefficients, tmp.coefficients);
        */
    }
}

void Polynomial::setCoefficient(std::size_t idx, double value)
{
    if (idx > degree)
        throw std::out_of_range("invalid index");
    coefficients[idx] = value;
}
```

```
std::vector<Polynomial> Polys;
Polynomial *P1 = new Polynomial(degreeInt);
P1->setCoefficient(idx, coefficient);
Polys.push_back(*P1);
delete P1;
```

That being said, the `coefficients` array would be better implemented using a `std::vector` instead. Let the compiler and STL do all the heavy work for you, eg:

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    std::size_t degree;
    std::vector<double> coefficients;

public:
    Polynomial(std::size_t aDegree = 0);

    void setDegree(std::size_t value);
    void setCoefficient(std::size_t idx, double value);
};

Polynomial::Polynomial(std::size_t aDegree)
    : degree(aDegree)
{
    if (degree == std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())
        throw std::domain_error("invalid degree value");
    coefficients.resize(degree + 1, double(0));
}

void Polynomial::setDegree(std::size_t value)
{
    if (degree != value)
    {
        if (value == std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())
            throw std::domain_error("invalid degree value");
        coefficients.resize(value + 1, double(0));
        degree = value;
    }
}

void Polynomial::setCoefficient(std::size_t idx, double value)
{
    coefficients[idx] = value;
}
```

Comment: Keeping my current implementation of the array [] coefficients I implemented a copy constructor and assignment operator that look like:  `degree = P.degree;
 coefficients = new double [degree + 1];
 for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
  coefficients[i] = P.coefficients[i];` This isn't working, how can I modify this to work?

Comment: @user88453 please edit your question to show your latest code, don't put it in comments.